# Pcap4j java library : unable to catch more than one packet using the same ping

Tags: java, packet-capture, pcap4j

when I capture a specific packet I can't reproduce the same thing using the same ping. ( for example when you run the project and you go the cmd "ping somethingthatdoesntwork.comm" result : couldn't reach the page, the second time you do the same ping nothing happens.

```
public class Pcap4jLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws PcapNativeException, IOException, NotOpenException, InterruptedException {
        String filter = null;
        if (args.length != 0) {
            filter = args[0];
        }

        PcapNetworkInterface nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
        if (nif == null) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        final PcapHandle handle = nif.openLive(65536, PromiscuousMode.NONPROMISCUOUS, 10);

        PacketListener listener = new PacketListener() {
            public void gotPacket(PcapPacket packet) {
                printPacket(packet, handle);
            }

        };

        while (true) {
            handle.loop(1, listener);
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private static void printPacket(Packet packet, PcapHandle ph) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (packet != null)
            if (packet.toString().contains("Question") && packet.toString().contains("Authority")) {
                System.out.println(packet.toString().split("DNS Header")[1].split("QNAME: ")[1].split("QTYPE")[0]);
                if (packet.toString().contains("RCODE: 3")) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't reach this page");
                }
                System.out.println("_______________________________________");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps packets arrive while your app sleeps :)

Comment: it's just for 10 ms and  i'm not that fast ^^

Comment: lol but 10 ms in terms of network speed is a lot. How many ping packets are you sending? You read 1 packet, that could take a few millis if not nanos and then sleep a lot. Try sending a lot of pings and see what happens.

Comment: i'm just checking if a certain page respond or not. i'm sending one ping every 10000 ms  it works when i use different addresses but not the same one

Comment: please, add how are you sending the ping command.

Comment: for example open cmd and try to ping awrongadress.comx while running this and then it's gonna show Couldn't reach this page, then try to do it again and nothing's gonna happen

Comment: Seems the error is in count value, see [here](https://programtalk.com/vs/pcap4j/pcap4j-sample/src/main/java/org/pcap4j/sample/Loop.java/). Try 1000 or something.